# Does Hyperledger fabric broadcast events multiple times per peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Let's say if i have 10 peers and I broadcast an event. Does that mean that event will be broadcast 10 times? So all the subcribers will be spammed times the amount of peers.

I couldn't find any information about this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different types of events:

1. Contract events - Those emitted explicitly by the chaincode
   developer within a transaction
2. Transaction (Commit) events - Those emitted automatically when a transaction is committed after an invoke
3. Block events - Those emitted automatically when a block is committed

Based on the type of events you're listening, you can apply filters on the eventHubs in order to catch only specific events.

[Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS SDK - How to listen events](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-listening-to-events.html)

[Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS SDK - Register Block event](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/ChannelEventHub.html#registerBlockEvent)

[Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS SDK - Register Tx event](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/ChannelEventHub.html#registerTxEvent)

[Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS SDK - Register Chaincode event](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/ChannelEventHub.html#registerChaincodeEvent)

Comment: But does the amount of time the transactions is executed (times amount of peers) effect the amount of times the event is broadcasted?

Comment: The events are broadcasted once the transaction are committed to the ledger, so they are effected by the amount of time requested to endorse and commit the transactions. You can find more details here:
https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-channel-events.html